# On key up Data is not search from array in js, showing indexOf is not an function

Tags: javascript, arrays, search, onkeyup

Code shown below throws following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: uniqueData[i].indexOf is not a function

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Search here" id="search">
```

```js
var input = document.getElementById('search');

uniqueData = [array of objects from api];

input.addEventListener("input", function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < uniqueData.length; i++) {
        if (uniqueData[i].indexOf(this.value) > -1) {
            console.log("Object with index number " + i + " contains " + this.value);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: what do you get when you `console.log(uniqueData)`?

Comment: Is `uniqueData[i]` an object?

Answer (score 0):

If seems like `uniqueData[i]` might be an object. If that's the case, you might want to do something like this, which will give you an array of values to search (`indexOf` is an array method, after all).

```
if (Object.values(uniqueData[i]).indexOf(this.value) > -1) {
  console.log("Object with index number " + i + " contains " + this.value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't using this in context.

You want to use the method below.

Note that "event" is passed in as a parameter to the function. 
The event is the input event.
The target of the event is the element in which the event is fired on.

```
input.addEventListener("input", function (event) {
    for (var i = 0; i < uniqueData.length; i++) {
        if (uniqueData[i].indexOf(event.target.value) > -1) {
            console.log("Object with index number " + i + " contains " + event.target.value);
        }
    }
});
```